# What is meant by the verb 'to class' (used in a military context)?

Tags: meaning, verbs, military

I read this in [an article](https://www.forces.net/news/tom-moore-military-guard-honour-army-veteran-completes-100-lap-challenge) about Captain Tom Moore:

> WO1 Jamie Pearson, Regimental Sergeant Major of 1st Battalion The Yorkshire Regiment, congratulated Tom as he watched him cross the finish line.
>
> "**We class Captain Tom as one of our own**, so it’s a fantastic honour to be here today to witness such an inspirational act from a phenomenal individual. Thank you Tom," he said.

1) What is the specific connotation and meaning of the verb 'class'?  I can see obviously that the general idea is that the person considers Captain Tom to be part of the regiment, but I have never encountered this verb before.  Is it short for 'classify'?

2) Is this army slang, or is the verb more widely used in British society?  (Or, is it a Yorkshire word as this is about the Yorkshire regiment?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a shortened form of "classify". It's recognized in this dictionary definition:

[American Heritage Dictionary "class"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=class)
transitive verb:
To arrange, group, or rate according to qualities or characteristics; assign to a class; classify.

The sense is in Merriam-Webster dictionary as well.

It's not particularly military jargon. It's used in the U.S., and evidently Britain.

Comment: I don't agree that 'class' (verb) is merely a shortened form of 'classify'.